# Excel:can I simplify creation of following pivot table and chart somehow?

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I have following table that lists all projects: ProjectId, DateCompleted. 
I want to create a table/chart that shows a total of projects completed each year/month.

I used =TEXT(DateCompleted,"MMM") to create a Month column. I also used =TEXT(DateCompleted,"YYYY") to create a Year column. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKzjw.jpg)

Selected all data, created a pivot chart that displays count of projects per month and year. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOJpB.jpg)

Is there any way not to create additional columns Months and Year and still have the same result? Can I create additional fields in PivotChart Fields menu based on my table data?